# Zenject Binding the classes of the Factory Object by Runtime Arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I have a Character class. Its mono and have CharacterInstaller. And I'm using MonoPoolableMemoryPool for Character pool. But I have to bind derived class by character runtime parameters. Is there any way to do that?

```
    public enum Type
    {
        MELEE,
        RANGED,
    }
    
    public class CharacterCreator
    {
        Character.Factory _factory;

        private void CreateMelee()
        {
            _factory.Create(Type.Melee);
        }
    }

 public class CharacterInstaller : MonoInstaller
    {
      
        public override void InstallBindings()
        {
            if (type == Type.Melee)
            {
                
                Container.Bind<IAttackSystem>.To<MeleeAttackSystem>();
            }
            else
            {
                Container.Bind<IAttackSystem>.To<RangedAttackSystem>();
            }
        }
        
}
```

I didnt find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pools in Zenject require specific prefabs per pool. Depending on how you're binding your pool you may need a different pool per character type.

It's hard to say without seeing how you're binding the pool. Can you show that, too?

Also, when using pools I've found that I need to do less injecting inside constructors and instead pass params into the factory/pool creation method and then cache the dynamic params with whatever pooled object is implementing Zenject.IPoolable.

**Here's how I'm binding my pool for projectiles:**

```
Container.BindFactory<Projectile.Settings, Projectile, Projectile.Factory>()
    .FromPoolableMemoryPool( pool => pool
        .FromSubContainerResolve()
        .ByNewContextPrefab( _gun.ProjectilePrefab )
        .WithGameObjectName( _gun.ProjectilePrefab.name )
        .UnderTransform( context => context.Container.ResolveId<Transform>( _gun.ProjectilePoolId ) )
    );
```

**Here's how I'm grabbing an available projectile:**

```
private readonly Projectile.Factory _factory;

// ...

Projectile newProjectile = _factory.Create( _projectileSettings );
```

**And, finally, here's the definiton for the Projectile:**

```
public class Projectile : 
    IPoolable<Projectile.Settings, IMemoryPool>, 
    IDisposable
{
    public void OnSpawned( Settings settings, IMemoryPool pool )
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _pool = pool;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _pool.Despawn( this );
    }

    public void OnDespawned()
    {
        _pool = null;

        // Handle despawn logic here.
        // Fire events, dispose other references, reset data, etc.
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Settings
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The important thing to note is that before I implemented pooled projectiles the `Settings` class *was* being directly injected into the Projectile and was readonly. But, now that it's pooled and these settings can change dynamically depending on who's firing the projectile I do not inject them and instead pass them in as creation params.

Finally, I think that if you can provide more info I can get a better understanding of what exactly the problem is. Hope you found this helpful!

**Here are two EXTREMELY helpful resources I've found when working with factories and pools:**

Memory Pools: https://github.com/Mathijs-Bakker/Extenject/blob/master/Documentation/MemoryPools.md

Sub Containers: https://github.com/Mathijs-Bakker/Extenject/blob/master/Documentation/SubContainers.md

Comment: Thank you. I use it the way you use it.  I know pool parameters but my problem slightly different. I want to change object bindings depending the arguments. It might be impossible after that object created. But i want to know if it.